# Parent method is not called in Parent Class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, parent-child

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.j = 0
        self.calc_i(865)

    def calc_i(self, i):
        self.i = 68 * i


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("i from B is", self.i)

    def calc_i(self, i):
        self.i = 37 * i


b = B()
```

The Code above should call the parent class method of **calc_i** according to my understanding because the parent class will run it's own method and it also doesn't know where it is being used as a parent.

But When I run it, it calls the child method where i * 37 and not the parent method

Comment: By writing `calc_i()` for the child, you override that name even before `__init__()` is called.

Comment: When you override a method, that _replaces_ the parent class version with your own; the original is no longer called automatically. If you want to make it be called explicitly, you need to write explicit code to do that, either using `super` or expecting calling `A.calc_i`. Making it expect lets you choose whether you want to call the parent version before, after, or somewhere in the middle of your own (and likewise lets you choose to do what you're doing now and not call the parent at all).

Comment: Just because `self.calc_i` is called in `A.__init__` doesn't mean `self.calc_i` *resolves* to `A.calc_i`. You do not know what the *runtime* type of `self` will be, and that's what determines which method gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because the parent class will run it's own method

No, it won't.

When `B.__init__` calls `super().__init__`, it's the same instance of `B` that gets passed to `A.__init__`. As a result, the evaluation of `self.calc_i` uses the method resolution order (MRO) of `B`, not `A`, to determine which `calc_i` method gets called. Because the MRO is `[B, A, object]`, and `B` defines `calc_i`, *that's* the method invoked by `self.calc_i(865)`.

The most important thing to remember when writing method is that *you don't know* the runtime type of `self`. The only thing you can be *reasonably* sure of is that `type(self)` will be a *subclass* of `A`, and you can't predict what methods that subclass will define.

If you absolutely need `A.__init__` to call `A.calc_i`, you need to be explicit:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.j = 0
    A.calc_i(self, 865)
```

or, define a method whose name makes it absolutely clear it should not (and cannot without some effort) be overridden.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.j = 0
    self.__calc_i(self, 865)

def __calc_i(self, i):
    self.i = 68 * i
```

If you want *some* uses of `calc_i` to be overridable, you can define

```
def calc_i(self, i):
    return self.__calc_i(i)
```

and use `self.__calc_i` when it *must* be `A`'s private implemeantion, and `self.calc_i` where you are OK with a subclass providing its own.